# MySQL in PHP - WHERE clause - not working

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

I have this code:

```
<?php
$user = $_COOKIE["user"];
$password = $_COOKIE["password"];
$localhost = "localhost";
$userdb = "xxxxx";
$passworddb = "xxxxx";
$database = "xxxxx";
$conn = mysqli_connect($localhost, $userdb, $passworddb, $database);
$vyber = "SELECT PASSWORD FROM Login WHERE User=".$user;
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $vyber);
echo $result;
?>
```

Cookie are set and if I use $vyber in database so everything is good. But there PHP write nothing. Can anybody tell, what I doing wrong? (Without comand $vyber every thing running perfect)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is query error change query to :

```
$vyber = "SELECT PASSWORD FROM Login WHERE User='$user'";
```

if did not work use die function to dispaly error message :

```
mysqli_query($conn, $vyber) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

To fetch records :

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row[0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of,

```
echo $result
```

try to do that :

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
    echo $row[0];
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately not work. Says: "Warning: mysqli_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result"